# upgrade foundation 3 to 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, zepto

i have recently just upgraded from foundation 3 to 4, though I have noticed that I cannot get zepto to work correctly. I keep getting the following

```
Started GET "/js/vendor/zepto.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-12 00:03:30 +1100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/js/vendor/zepto.js"):
```

i have followed the instructions to a tee, and googled to try and find a solution without any luck

this is in my footer

```
= javascript_include_tag :application
:javascript
  document.write('<script src=/js/vendor/'
    + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
    + '.js><\/script>');
/ Check for Zepto support, load jQuery if necessary
```

Comment: What instructions did you follow (link please)? What version of rails are you using (for example, if you're using 3.1+, your route should start with `/assets`, not `/js` if you're serving the file through the asset pipeline.

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/

Comment: `Paul-McGuanes-MacBook:teammngt paulmcguane$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.3
Paul-McGuanes-MacBook:teammngt paulmcguane$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]`

Comment: that has zepto being served, non of the foundation js elements are working

Comment: @Deefour with that little tweak, and a clean of my assets its all working. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recompiled assets and issue was fixed